# captive portal session lockup

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, login, session, gateway, captive-portal

I'm using an internet at an apartment where they utilize a captive portal. All seems to be fine, but sometime when I try to use I got a message saying that "You are already logged in" but I can't use the internet. I had to manually click logoff, only then I can login again.

Do you have any idea of the cause of this? The server is Ubuntu server 10.04 and the gateway software is propritary.

Here is some info

```
Idle timeout = 10 mins
session timeout = unlimited
simutanous user = 1
```

Thanks